# Recover a Deleted Branch when I have already created the branch with the same name

Tags: branch, recover

I have deleted one of the Test branch named 12.04 and created a new branch off of 12.01 branch and name it 12.04. Now I would like to recover the code I have in the old 12.04 branch which I have deleted earlier. when  I set my options to show deleted branches I don't see the deleted 12.04 branch.I know its kind of weird but can someone help me in that please how to recover the old 12.04 code which i have deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your original changes will be saved with an associated revision number in your repository.  The trick is now to find which revision number matches the old 12.04 branch code.  The stackoverflow thread below may be of assistance in determining the correct revision number.

[How to "undelete" a deleted folder in Subversion / TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265369/how-to-undelete-a-deleted-folder-in-subversion-tortoisesvn)